# Not able to understand !~ in regex

Tags: regex, perl

My requirement is to pass a string with + (eg: ABC+DEF). And it should match with any value for actual_state, values can be `ABC+DEF   ABC+DEF,   ABC+DEF,,` etc .Here there can be one or more comma after ABC+DEF. But it should not match with `ABC+DEF, PQR-SL`.

Below is the code snippet what i tried:

```
sub verify_state{
     my $expected_state = shift;
     my $vol            = 'vol';
     my $actual_state   = 'ABC+DEF,';
     print "Verify backend state for $vol\n";
     print "Expected backend state for $vol = $expected_state\n";
     print "Actual backend state for $vol = $actual_state\n";
     if ( $expected_state !~ /$actual_state,*$/ ) {
         print
             "Expected state was $expected_state but got $actual_state for $vol\n"
         ;
         return 0;
     }
     return 1;
 }

 my $val = verify_state('ABC+DEF');
 print $val,"\n";
```

it should return me 1 if i will pass `ABC+DEF`.
0 if i will pass `ABC+DEF, PQR-SL`

why i wrote `my $actual_state   = 'ABC+DEF,';`
Because the values `ABC+DEF   ABC+DEF,   ABC+DEF,,` are coming as a part of a hash value for a specific key eg. `my $actual_state   = $status->{state};` .

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Can you [edit] the question and just make a list of expected output for each of the strings you put in? It sounds like your pattern is wrong, but I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: `!~` means *does not match* (is just the logical opposite of `=~`)

Comment: @simbabque , in my case actual_state can be any thing out of `ABC+DEF   ABC+DEF,   ABC+DEF,,` as i dont have control over it .but what i am passing is constant here i.e `ABC+DEF` .  i am trying to match negatively  ABC+DEF with what ever will be there with actual_state. i mean ABC+DEF !~ ABC+DEF  or ABC+DEF !~ ABC+DEF,   or ABC+DEF !~ ABC+DEF,, . For all cases it should be false and return 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a comma `,` hardcoded in your `$actual_state`. So it cannot match the input you are testing with, `ABC+DEF` without a comma. The way you build the pattern you also need to escape the `+` (thanks to [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman)), so

```
my $actual_state = 'ABC\+DEF';
```

and the posted code works in my tests.

This assumes that your input must indeed end with that string, optionally followed only by commas.

Comment: He also needs to escape the `+`. Currently this matches `ABCCCDEF` but not `ABC+DEF`

Comment: working fine after skipping + and removing comma. Thank you and @slebetman

Comment: @Satya Great, glad it helped.  Let me know if any explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

> why i wrote my $actual_state   = 'ABC+DEF,'; Because the values
>   ABC+DEF   ABC+DEF,   ABC+DEF,, are coming as a part of a hash value
>   for a specific key eg. my $actual_state   = $status->{state}; .

If that's the case then you can either remove trailing comma(s) from `$actual_state` or ignore them in pattern matching.

Also use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html). See below example to get an idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $expected = qr{ABC+DEF};
my $actual_state = qr{ABC+DEF};
#my $actual_state = qr{ABC+DEF,};
#my $actual_state = qr{ABC+DEF,,};
#if $actual_state has comma then you can do search and replace
$actual_state =~ s/,//g;
print "Matched" if $expected =~ /\Q$actual_state\E/;
#prints "Matched"
```

Comment: replaced **,** and used **quotemeta** for skipping + , working fine for me. Thank you